# how to access the .properties file in ant if it is in different location

Tags: java, ant, properties-file

```
<property file="Build.properties"/>
```

this is valid if `build.properties` file is in root of project.now if the Build.properties file is in src folder and `build.xml` is in root(main project root).then what will be the syntax to access that `build.properties` file.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by giving in two ways

1. give the loction in classpath.
2. `<property file="src/build.properties" />`

Both of them worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can define property at starting of your ant script. 

And 
use ${proj_home}*.properties to access your property file. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are valid.  Note that you can pass a property file as ant command line

```
ant -propertyfile src/build.properties
```